# Integer read from plist always returns 0

Tags: ios, plist

I'm trying to get a value of integer number from plist.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Prop" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
int number = [[[dict objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"Quant"] intValue];
NSLog(@"Quant is %d",number);
```

The plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>Quant</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
```

App runs but the value of the number is always 0.
I have been reading various manuals whole day, but can't find the error.

Comment: Is that the entire plist file?

Comment: Yes, this is entire plist. And your question helped me to notice the error. I looked at the file as property list and saw the Root header, but there is no Root in the source code. Remove Root from the code and all is right working, thanks.

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer and accept it.